# Parsing HTTP_RANGE header in PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, range, http-headers

Is there an existing way to parse the `HTTP_RANGE` header correctly in PHP? Thought I'd ask here before re-inventing the wheel.

I am currently using

```
preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);
```

to parse the header but that does not cover all possible values of the header so I am wondering if there is a function or library that can do this already?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this, but I'd have a crack at it with regular expressions. Take a look at the specification http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather use regex to **test** it before sending a [`416`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.17). Then just *parse* it by exploding on the comma `,` and the hyphen `-`. I also see that you used `\d+` in your regex, but those are actually **not** required. When either of the range indexes is omitted, then it just means "first byte" or "last byte". You should cover that in your regex as well. Also see the [Range header in the HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) how you're supposed to handle it.

Kickoff example:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    if (!preg_match('^bytes=\d*-\d*(,\d*-\d*)*$', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header('Content-Range: bytes */' . filelength); // Required in 416.
        exit;
    }

    $ranges = explode(',', substr($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 6));
    foreach ($ranges as $range) {
        $parts = explode('-', $range);
        $start = $parts[0]; // If this is empty, this should be 0.
        $end = $parts[1]; // If this is empty or greater than than filelength - 1, this should be filelength - 1.

        if ($start > $end) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header('Content-Range: bytes */' . filelength); // Required in 416.
            exit;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Edit: $start must always be less than $end

Comment: You're welcome. Disclaimer: untested. This is less or more translated in head from my Java Servlet example here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html

Comment: The [RFC specification for byte ranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) also allows something like `bytes=-500` which is a valid request for the last 500 bytes of a file. This makes it a bit more complicated to extract the range than just exploding on the `-` character.

Comment: This answer is wrong when it states that when start is missing it should be treated as 0. As Andrew Theis said, when you see something like bytes=-500, it's a request for the end of the file, NOT bytes=0-500.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [PEAR Package HTTP_Download](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Download/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_HTTP_Download__HTTP_Download-1.1.3Download.php.html):

```
function getRanges()
{
    return preg_match('/^bytes=((\d*-\d*,? ?)+)$/', @$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches) ? $matches[1] : array();
}
```

It is also a good idea to use [this](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Download) [packages](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Header/) for stuff like this!

Answer (score 1):

There's a snippet implementing HTTP range support on the `fread()` page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php#84115

Comment: This helps, but it's buggy. Use as a guide only.