# HTML5 Audio Element " src = get.php cannot skip position

Tags: php, javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I am using the HTML5 AudioElement to play my .mp3 files, but I noticed it is not possible to skip the position. I am fetching the file via PHP from outside the www root.

I am using HTML code :

```
<audio src="" controls id="appAudio" style="width:1000px;margin-top:10px"></audio>
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById('appAudio').src= 'http://localhost/index.php/player/get_audio_via_php/1';
```

PHP code:

```
    $file = "/myfolder/1.mp3";
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    return file_get_contents($file);
```

Like I said it does play the audio file, but skipping position is not possible.
Is there a solution to this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the browser doesn't have the file in cache, "skipping" causes the browser to send a new request, with a ["range" header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests). Your PHP file needs to handle this header.

this means:

1. [get and parse the range header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209204/parsing-http-range-header-in-php)
2. [respond to the request with status code 206 and corresponding range headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157318/resumable-downloads-when-using-php-to-send-the-file)
3. [output only necessary bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)

Comment: Thank you. I will look further into this. But is there a simple method to fetch audio files which are outside the www root?

Comment: Depending on your webserver configuration, you could create a symlink. http://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks

Comment: Do you have a working example of how to implement the range headers? I can´t a single working example...

Comment: I have found this but not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340276/make-mp3-seekable-php

Comment: I used his script but it does not load my mp3.

Comment: did you specify the correct content-type (second parameter to function)? 

`serve_file_resumable($file, 'audio/mpeg');`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this post, related to [serving mp3 files via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516661/can-i-serve-mp3-files-with-php).

The answer suggests changing the content-type to include several types:

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question... I used this, seems to be working on Chrome.

```
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
    header('Content-Disposition:: inline; filename="'.$audio->filename.'"');
    header('Content-length: '.$fileSize);
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    readfile($filepath);
```