# html5 audio player with no cache

Tags: html, html5-audio, no-cache

I want to have a html5 audio player that plays  a shoutcast stream with no cache.
I've tried the answer given here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271131/9253598)
and tried to load the stream with a php file,

But it doesn't work for me, what am i doing wrong?
So the script i use is below...

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay="" controls="" src="<shoutcast ip>+<port>/stream.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

and script:

```
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("ended",function() {
    this.src = "<shoutcast ip>+<port>/stream.mp3?nocache="+new Date().getTime();
    this.play();
});
```

Comment: If the file src is accessible to the Client through HTML or JavaScript, they have access to it anyways.

Comment: sorry, i meant the player works, but the part +new Date().getTime(); doesnt work

Comment: Try `Date.now()`, without `new`.

Comment: No luck, still loads the normal source without cache busting

Comment: can this (cache busting) also be done in the <audio> tag ?
When i look at any shoutcast DNAS page, al the html5 audio players seems to do this with the source <code> ?type=http&;nocache=randomnumber" </code>
and there is nothing to see in the script on the source code that the script edits the src in the audio player

Comment: If you use a `.php` src, that should not be cashed. Just save the audio file as `.php` instead of its regular file extension.