# javascript and jquery loop audio sound in reliable way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through the same audio that I have, but it seems like it sometimes work, and sometimes doesn't, and sometimes it only sound part of the times he supposed to,

Is there a reliable way to ensure of playing the sound? and so it won't go to the next iteration of the for loop until it finishes the sound?

That's the mainly code I have:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("hitSound").play();
    }, 500*i);
}
```

**edit**: another problem:

Sometimes it doesn't play the audio at all, which is a bit strange, is there a way to call a func when the audio is finished? just to make sure it was played already?

I also tried this code:

```
myAudio = new Audio('someSound.ogg');
myAudio.loop = true;
myAudio.play();
```

Comment: can you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 audio ended function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271082/html5-audio-ended-function)