# How to catch 'stop' event in HTML5 audio and then do something?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'am beginner in HTML5 and not even middle in JS, but I'am trying to figure out how to correctly use `<audio>` and smth else... so i've got this question... my html:

```
<i class='some_icon' onclick='play();'>
  <audio src='some_mp3.mp3' id='player'></audio>
</i>
```

Now when I click on the icon I want some mp3 file play and it works because I wrote this js:

```
function play() {
    var my = document.getElementById('player');
    if (my.paused) {
      my.play();
    } else {
      my.pause();
      my.currentTime = 0
    }
  }
```

BUT, besides, I want to change my icon WHEN that mp3 file ENDS... how can I do that? Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: by stopped, you mean ended?

Comment: @Mike yeah, cause ended, sorry for my engl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 audio element with dynamic source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190160/html5-audio-element-with-dynamic-source)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code to trigger some code when your audio ( or video ) ends:

```
var my = document.getElementById('player');

my.addEventListener("ended", function(e){
  // here goes your code to change the icon
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was answered/accepted yesterday but i just thought I'd share a full working bit of code for future users benefit. (the sound clip is only 4 secs long)

```js
 function play() {
   var my = document.getElementById('player');
   my.currentTime = 0;
   /**this one loops***/
   if ($('.btn').find('span i').hasClass('fa-stop')) {
     $('.btn').find('span i').removeClass('fa-stop').addClass('fa-play-circle');
     $('.texto').text("Play");
   }
   if (my.paused) {
     my.play();
   } else {
     my.pause();
     my.currentTime = 0;
   }
   my.addEventListener("ended", function(e) {
     $('.btn').find('span i').removeClass('fa-play-circle').addClass('fa-stop');
     $('.texto').text("Stop");
   });
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Audio Icon Toggle</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="music">
    <h2>Audio Icon Toggle</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#player" onclick="play();"><span><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="texto">Play</span></span>
      <audio src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/monkey.mp3" id="player" class="collapse"></audio>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```