# HTML5 video element with dynamic source

Tags: php, html, video, html5-video

From this topic [HTML5 audio element with dynamic source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190160/html5-audio-element-with-dynamic-source) I use this part of code very well:

```
<audio id="player" controls="controls" autoplay="true" loop="loop"><source   src="song.php" type="audio/mpeg" /> </audio>
```

song.php:

```
$file = "something.mp3";
header("Content-Type:audio/mpeg");
header("Content-LEngth:".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Now I want to do the same with videos mp4.

```
<video autoplay="true" controls src="video.php" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

video.php:

```
$file = "something.mp4";
header("Content-Type:video/mp4");
header("Content-LEngth:".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

but this doesn't work, the video isn't playing. Any idea how I can  prevent to deliver the URL to the video ?

Comment: Are you sure that something.mp4 file exist in the same directory where video.php is? If yes - is it properly encoded? Are there any JS errors in the DEV console?

Comment: yes, the file exists and is playable.

Comment: do you think it must work ? the complete code is a little bit more complicated, maybe I must serach at a other place ?

Comment: Could you please open DEV console (F12) and check for any JS errors. Also, does the Video element show some error? Add some text <video autoplay="true" controls src="video.php" type="video/mp4">You see this only if the format is corrupted or not supported</video>

Comment: the only errormsg in DEV is Http 500 and the controls in the videobox are only short visible and then hidden. The erromsg is : the video-format ore Mimetype not supported.

Comment: The error is probably in your video.php file. Could you enable the errors with these lines at the beginning of the file: 

            
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 2):

I stripped out my testcode:

```
<audio controls ><source src="content_de/media.php?t=1&f=something.mp3"   type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
<br><br>
<video autoplay="true" controls src="content_de/media.php?t=2&f=something.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

and the media.php:

```
$file = 'C:\\media\\de\\w\\' . $f;
if (file_exists($file)) {
   if ($t == 1) {

    header("Content-Type:audio/mpeg");
    header("Content-Length:".filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}



if ($t == 2) {
    header("Content-Type:video/mp4");

    header("Content-Length:".filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
 }
}
```

the audio is playing well, then video not.