# How to embed an audio file into php website

Tags: php, html, audio

I want to embed audio files into php website.  But I found it impossible because there is no such tag or function in php as in html5 where tag audio can be displayed in a website. I hope there is an easy way to achieve it. If there's not, I hope your solution will be as detailed as possible. Thanks!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190160/html5-audio-element-with-dynamic-source

Comment: Anything you can do in HTML you can do with PHP, too. You can use `echo` to output html5 code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no such tag or function in php as in html5

If the output of your PHP file has a HTML5 doctype (and the content type `text/html`), it will be interpreted as HTML5.

There are several ways to output HTML code in a PHP file:

1. echo

```php
    <?php
        echo '<p>This is a <b>paragraph</b>.</p>';
    ?>
```

2. plain output

```php
    <p>This is a <b>paragraph</b>.</p>
```

3. conditional output

```php
    <?php if ($condition) { ?>

    <p>This is only printed if the condition is true.</p>

    <?php } ?>
```

Besides `echo` there are some more functions to output text: `var_dump` and `printf`, for example.

Comment: hi aloso, i changed my mind, i'm now using html5 to capture an audio file now. here's my code in java script.                   var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  var mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(s);
  recorder = new Recorder(mediaStreamSource);
  recorder.record();                     an error happened here which shows that recorder is not defined here. do i miss any headfile here?please help me out.