# Requests with multiple connections

Tags: python, networking, download, python-requests

I use the Python Requests library to download a big file, e.g.:

```
r = requests.get("http://bigfile.com/bigfile.bin")
content = r.content
```

The big file downloads at +- 30 Kb per second, which is a bit slow. Every connection to the bigfile server is throttled, so I would like to make multiple connections.

Is there a way to make multiple connections at the same time to download one file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use HTTP [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header to fetch just part of file ([already covered for python here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798879/download-file-using-partial-download-http)).

Just start several threads and fetch different range with each and you're done ;)

```
def download(url,start):
    req = urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org/')
    req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (start, start+chunk_size)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    parts[start] = f.read()

threads = []
parts = {}

# Initialize threads
for i in range(0,10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=download, i*chunk_size)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# Join threads back (order doesn't matter, you just want them all)
for i in threads:
    i.join()

# Sort parts and you're done
result = ''.join(parts[i] for i in sorted(parts.keys()))
```

Also note that not every server supports `Range` header (and especially servers with [php scripts responsible for data fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209204/parsing-http-range-header-in-php) often don't implement handling of it).

Answer (score 7):

Here's a Python script that saves given url to a file and uses multiple threads to download it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from functools import partial
from itertools import count, izip
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads
from urllib2 import HTTPError, Request, urlopen

def download_chunk(url, byterange):
    req = Request(url, headers=dict(Range='bytes=%d-%d' % byterange))
    try:
        return urlopen(req).read()
    except HTTPError as e:
        return b''  if e.code == 416 else None  # treat range error as EOF
    except EnvironmentError:
        return None

def main():
    url, filename = sys.argv[1:]
    pool = Pool(4) # define number of concurrent connections
    chunksize = 1 << 16
    ranges = izip(count(0, chunksize), count(chunksize - 1, chunksize))
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        for s in pool.imap(partial(download_part, url), ranges):
            if not s:
                break # error or EOF
            file.write(s)
            if len(s) != chunksize:
                break  # EOF (servers with no Range support end up here)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The end of file is detected if a server returns empty body, or 416 http code, or if the response size is not `chunksize` exactly.

It supports servers that doesn't understand `Range` header (everything is downloaded in a single request in this case; to support large files, change `download_chunk()` to save to a temporary file and return the filename to be read in the main thread instead of the file content itself).

It allows to change independently number of concurrent connections (pool size) and number of bytes requested in a single http request.

To use multiple processes instead of threads, change the import:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool # use processes (other code unchanged)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires the linux utility named "aria2c", but it has the advantage of easily resuming downloads.

It also assumes that all the files you want to download are listed in the http directory list for location `MY_HTTP_LOC`.  I tested this script on an instance of lighttpd/1.4.26 http server. But, you can easily modify this script so that it works for other setups.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import urllib
import re
import subprocess

MY_HTTP_LOC = "http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/"

# retrieve webpage source code
f = urllib.urlopen(MY_HTTP_LOC)
page = f.read()
f.close

# extract relevant URL segments from source code
rgxp = '(\<td\ class="n"\>\<a\ href=")([0-9a-zA-Z\(\)\-\_\.]+)(")'
results =  re.findall(rgxp,str(page))
files = []
for match in results:
    files.append(match[1])

# download (using aria2c) files
for afile in files:
    if os.path.exists(afile) and not os.path.exists(afile+'.aria2'):
        print 'Skipping already-retrieved file: ' + afile
    else:
        print 'Downloading file: ' + afile          
        subprocess.Popen(["aria2c", "-x", "16", "-s", "20", MY_HTTP_LOC+str(afile)]).wait()
```

Comment: If you really only need to download 1 file, then just go to a terminal on linux (if you are using linux) and run `aria2c -x 16 -s 20 <insert-URL-here>`.  I like my solution because whenever I have multiple big files (or even just 1 big file) that I need to download, I just throw them into the `MY_HTTP_LOC` directory, and then run my script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a module called [pypdl](https://pypi.org/project/pypdl/) or [pySmartDL](https://pypi.org/project/pySmartDL/) for this, they provide option to use multiple threads and can do a lot more. Also these module gives a download bar by default.
for more info check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72633174/16915996)