# How to unfreeze requests download file in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I wrote a python script that downloads files from the internet. However everytime I run the script, it seems like my computer is frozen.

Codes:

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
     for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=2048):
         if chunk:  

              f.write(chunk)

              f.flush()
```

What can I do to this to load so my computer doesn't freeze?

Should I allocate a limited amount of ram? Or should I create a thread to do this?

Any advice would be appreciated. ty.

Comment: It could be that you're computer can't reach the site, and because I think get() is a blocking call, this could appear like it's frozen. Can you show us more of the code? Do you have any proof that you're reaching the site that you're trying to download from?

Comment: Well python is not C. The reason that your computer appears to freeze is because you have a very tight loop that doesn't exit Is this your real code?

Comment: why not control your resources from the shell before you execute your script, for example in linux `nice ` or `cpulimit` can control your resources

Comment: my guess is that it's a very large file... are you working with a small amount of RAM or an old processor?  to test my theory, try `for chunk in tqdm.tqdm(response.iter_content(chunk_size=2048):`

Comment: As e4c5 states, above code does not exit, so it will probably only terminate after maybe keyboard interrupt? Also see the following question and answer. Looks to be what you want to do.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py

Comment: @SH7890 yes it seems like a blocking call, I got the file downloaded and saved. It just seems like my whole computer got frozen when downloading it.  thought my computer is duel core.

Comment: @e4c5 yes it's the real code. I read it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py

Comment: @ZevAverbach it's pretty big, i had 4 gb ram. But not sure if there is a proper async way to make the download more responsive.

Comment: +1 for @zwer's answer, but in case you want to speed things up, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973531/4386191

Comment: @ZevAverbach yours what i'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @suvy i will give it a try too.  thanks for point cpulimit out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd increase the chunk size and add some breathing room for the underlying I/O thread, so:

```
import time

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024):  # lets use 1 meg chunks
        if chunk:  
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)  # 50ms delay won't kill anyone
```

If that doesn't help, you have deeper issues on your system / in your code than this piece.