# Please explain '%' usage in python

Tags: python, syntax

I'm learning multithreading in python and I was reading through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973531/8859876). I understand most of the code however there is this one line which I simply don't understand and I don't know how to search for it on Google as the '%' sign keeps returning modulo.

```
req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (start, start+chunk_size)
```

I thought that req.headers['Range'] would retrieve some 'range' element from an array however here they are assigning it a value of 'bytes=%s-%s' % (start, start+chunk_size). I really just don't understand what is going on in this line. Things like 'bytes=%s-%s' I am assuming is some sort of python syntax which I am unaware of. If you could explain each term in this line that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python there are multiple ways to format strings. using `%s` inside a string and then a `%` after the string followed by a tuple (or a single value), allows you to create a new string:

```
x = 5
y = 8
'my favourite number is %s, but I hate the number %s' % (x, y)
```

results in:

```
'my favourite number is 5, but I hate the number 8'
```

I think they call it C-type string formatting. For more information, you can check out [this page](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting).

In my opinion, it is easier to format string using f'strings, or `.format()`. Check out [this page](https://pyformat.info/) too

Comment: Thank you this helped alot! 'C-type string formatting' is the search term i needed to research this further.